# Frame image Broken in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage, nine-patch

I'm a newbie IOS developer. Today I made an app in order which adds frames to images. However, I encounter a problem when I blend two images together.
My frame design is a Rectangle and my main Image is a Rectangle (horizontal, vertical) or a square. When I blend two images together, my frame breaks because the 2 images are not same size.
If you could help me solve this issue or share any resources you have that would be greatly appreciated.
I am using `GPUImage` to blend the 2 images. I have also tried nine-patch (9-patch) and images vector but I have not been successful with either...
https://forumhumgeduvn.000webhostapp.com/qe/a.html
Thank you for reading.

Comment: did u try resizing the images to same size and load into ur design frame ?

Comment: please share the code

Comment: can you please explain more what di you mean byblending 2 images?

Comment: To solve this for yourself, use GIMP or some other image editor and make a step by step manual process that does what you want the app to do.  Then, try to code each step (and check the result of that 1 step_.  When you have a problem doing that, explain the exact step (NOT THE WHOLE PROCESS) that you need help with.

Comment: My question in link. 
https://forumhumgeduvn.000webhostapp.com/qe/a.html

Sorry i design not good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cut frame with CGmake and eidt it.

Comment: i do it. why you answer late :(